# Delphi, label max characters

Tags: delphi, label

`TLabel` has its maximum characters 255(ShortString) but I need more than that. What should I use?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, there is no limit. I just tried to use a string with 1223 characters as the caption of a `TLabel`, and that works. *In code*, however, a *string literal* cannot exceed 255 characters. But that is not a problem. Just do

```
Label1.Caption := 'This is a test. This is a test. This is a test.' + 
  'This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test.' +
  'This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test.' +
  'This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test.' +
  'This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test.' +
  'This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test.' +
  'This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test.';
```

You can make the caption as long as you wish, but a single string literal, the text in the source code between ' and ', cannot exceed 255 characters. To construct a longer string,
use the string concatenation operator (`+`) to concatenate shorter string literals.

Comment: please don't answer questions with `testtesttesttesttest` after all this time you should know better. lol